# Get IP address of android on virtual box

Tags: android, ip-address, virtualbox

I am writing a script to test an application by running [Android 4.3](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-4.3-20130725.iso&can=2&q=) in headless (no GUI) mode. I wish to get the IP address of the guest machine from the host machine.

This rules out using `ifconfig` on the console for android (ALT + F1).
Also android guest does not support guest additions, so using variations of `VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate <vm>` does not give the ip address.

Are there any other ways to obtain the ip address? I am also willing to change the ip address, if getting the ip address is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any thing for extracting the ip. I ended up setting specific MAC address to the vm and then configured a virtual router, `vyatta`, to assign a specific ip-address to that MAC address by adding a static route.

Answer (score 1):

ifconfig is correct. But the android shell can also be accessed with adb:

So simply run on the host:

```
adb shell ifconfig eth0
```

Comment: but to connect with adb I need the ip address. :(